# MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="ReadAttribute" Failing

Tags: msbuild, msbuildextensionpack

I cannot read the value attribute of `<add name="ReleaseVersion" value="4"/>` in the app.config below. I am at a complete loss. I suspect the XPath value or a Key value.

#### Target

```
  <Target Name="xxx"
          DependsOnTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" >

    <ItemGroup>
      <_DestinationAppConfigFile Include="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath->'$(OutDir)%(TargetPath)')" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="ReadAttribute"
                                       File="%(_DestinationAppConfigFile.FullPath)"
                                       XPath="/configuration/system.diagnostics/switches/add[@name='ReleaseVersion']/@value"
                                       Value="$(ReleaseVersion)" />

    <Error Condition = " '$(ReleaseVersion)'=='' "
           Text="Failed to read attribute." />

    <Message Text="ReleaseVersion: $(ReleaseVersion)"
             Importance="high" />

  </Target>
```

#### App.Config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
      <switches>
        <!-- ReleaseVersion (Conditional release switch); 0- = PRODUCTION, 1 = MIRROR, 2 = EMERGENCYRELEASE, 3 = USERACCEPTANCETESTING, 4 = QA, 5 = DEVELOPMENT, 6 = DRN DEVELOPMENT -->
        <add name="ReleaseVersion" value="4"/>
        <!-- Stop (Stops execution to allow for Just-In-Time (JIT) debugging); 0 = CONTINUE EXECUTION, 1 = LAUNCH DEBUGGER -->
        <add name="Stop" value="0"/>
      </switches>
    </system.diagnostics>
  </configuration>
```

#### Update

I reviewed the code for `XmlFile.ReadAttribute` at http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/83099#1714660 and it makes the call `SelectSingleNode` using the namespace syntax. That could be the problem.

```
    private void ReadAttribute()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.XPath))
        {
            this.Log.LogError("XPath is Required");
            return;
        }

        this.LogTaskMessage(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, "Read Attribute: {0}", this.XPath));
        XmlNode node = this.xmlFileDoc.SelectSingleNode(this.XPath, this.namespaceManager);
        if (node != null && node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
        {
            this.Value = node.Value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sample code is almost correct; it just needs a slight change to the usage of the XmlFile task. The call to XmlFile ReadAttribute should declare **Value** as the task's output. To do this, [add the Output element to the task declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164287.aspx), set to the `TaskParameter` value to "Value" and set the `PropertyName` value to "ReleaseVersion", similar to the following:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile 
        TaskAction="ReadAttribute"
        File="[example-path-to-app-config]"
        XPath="/configuration/system.diagnostics/switches/add[@name='ReleaseVersion']/@value">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="ReleaseVersion" />
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile>
```

After making the change, the attribute value should be found/read by the task, assuming your ToolsVersion is set to the version needed by your particular implementation of MSBuild Extension Pack